# Do I need different encryption and decryption algorithms for each key?

Tags: encryption, keys, symmetric

[image]

Is a different encryption and decryption algorithm used for every secret key, or can I use the same encryption and decryption algorithm for different keys?

Comment: The point of separating the key from the algorithm is precisely so that everybody can safely use the same algorithms with their own keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the same ones (which is good, because otherwise you'd run out of them pretty fast). In fact, when a cipher allows you to choose a key, that's basically the same as giving you a new pair of encryption/decryption algorithms for every key.

Usually, when designing a system that uses symmetric encryption, a small set of ciphers are used. For example, the popular [NaCl library](https://nacl.cr.yp.to/) only uses Salsa20+Poly1305 and AES-GCM.

Answer (score 0):

It depends from the algorithm that you will use. For example DES algorithm has a little different way for Encrypt/Decrypt for every key but Vigerene does not.